# Square the Sector

Tags: geometry

I would like to find the largest possible square that fits in a sector of a circle with radius $r$ and arc length $\theta \leq \pi$. Method doesn't matter here - a straightedge-and-compass construction is just as good as a set of coordinate equations.

Comment: For $\theta\ge\pi$ take the square with side length $\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}r$ and the circle center on the middle of one side. (Why is this maximal?)

Comment: Well, yes. The application I'm using this for is exclusively $\theta \leq \pi$, though. Thanks anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the angle is $\theta$ (the length of the arc would be $r\theta$).  I'll suppose $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.  There are two plausible
configurations:

[image]

[image]

Unless I've made an error, in the first configuration the side length $a$ of the square is $a_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\tan^2(\theta) + 2 \tan(\theta) + 1}}$.  In the second it is
$a_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3 + 2 \sin(\theta) - 2 \cos(\theta)}}$.
It seems that $a_2 > a_1$ for all $\theta$ in this interval.

Comment: (1) In addition, a proof is needed to show that the maximum is not reached in any other than these two "plausible" configurations.

(2) For small $\theta$, the second configuration is clearly better than the first.